# Configure SBT to resolve only jar (and not war) from Ivy repository

Tags: maven, jar, sbt, ivy, artifactory

I am building two projects using SBT and Ivy/Artifactory.

One of the projects is uploaded to Artifactory in JAR and WAR formats.
The other project uses the JAR built by SBT from the other project as a dependency.

My problem is: when I add my Artifactory repo and build the 2nd project, it successfully finds the artifact, but downloads both the JAR and WAR, whilst only the JAR file is desired.

I looked for documentation on the problem, but couldn't find anything specific to the extension. I read about classifiers in the SBT documentation page but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is to set 2 different ivy config, one for jar and one for war.

Then in your **dependent** project you can do:

```
“my.kikou.org” %% “dependeeProj” % “1.0” % “war”
```

Or

```
“my.kikou.org” %% “dependeeProj” % “1.0” % “jar”
```

So in your **dependee** project `dependeeProj` SBT file you can setup the ivy configuration by following this:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Artifacts.html#Modifying+default+artifacts

The goal is to generate an ivy.xml that contains 2 config (one for jar and one for war) and make the artifacts (the .jar and the .war) a part of the right config. The generated (by SBT) ivy.xml should look something like this:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    ...
    <configurations>
        <conf name="jar" description="Lib as a Jar"/>
        <conf name="war" description="Lib as a War"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="dependeeProj-jar" type="jar"  conf="jar" ext="jar"/>
        <artifact name="dependeeProj-war" type="war"  conf="war" ext="war"/>
    </publications>
    ...
</ivy-module>
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi Joan. Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I understand when you're talking about the dependency and when you're talking about the dependent project. Where do I need two ivy configs? Currently in my local Ivy repo the dependency has two directories, one is `jars` with the jar and the other is `wars` with the war. If I try with `% "jar"` in the build.sbt of the dependent project I get an error saying the configuration doesn't exist.

Comment: I edited the answer. What you have done in the dependent project is all you need to do. Now you need to do some more complicated work in the dependee project to generate that ivy.xml with the 2 configs and make each artifact a part of the right config. Unfortunately this is something I've never personally done but hopefully the link above will put you on the right way. Feel free to edit my answer when you will get that right.